# Simplify / Combine jQuery Snippet

Tags: jquery

I have 2 small jQuery snippets and would add more similar ones in this kind of rudimentary way ;

```
$(document).on('click', '.show-listings', function(e) {
    $(".facetwp-radio[data-value=listings]").click();
});
$(document).on('click', '.show-albums', function(e) {
    $(".facetwp-radio[data-value=albums]").click();
});
```

How can I rewrite this to make it more dynamic such that I could write 'show-XXX' where XXX= the value of the [data-value]

All help appreciated.

UPDATE

So the answer provided by @Pinguto worked very well but there is 1 unforseen consequence.

If I add an extra unrelated class, say for styling, like this....

```
    $(document).on('click', '.show-listings .another-random-class', function(e) {
    $(".facetwp-radio[data-value=listings]").click();
});
```

.. then I get an error in console as BOTH classes are being 'detected' and the code breaks.

How can I limit the scope of the code to only consider the class that has '.show-' in it?

FIXED

So some of the markup changed in the interim but this solution finally worked...

```
$(document).on('click', "a[class*='show-']", function(e) {
var c = $(this).attr('class');  // I read the class of the element 
c = c.slice(c.indexOf('show-')) // I delete any classes prior to the desired one 
    .split(' ')[0]              // I delete any classes following the desired one
    .slice('show-'.length);     // I delete the "show-" from the class 
$(".facetwp-facet .label[data-value="+ c +"]").click();  // If the element exists, then it simulates a click on it.
```

});

So thank you so much @Pinguto . Greatly appreciated.

ADDITIONAL REQUIREMENT

I wonder can we extend this code to allow for more than 1 'show' class?

That is to say ;

```
        $(document).on('click', '.show-listings .show-members .another-random-class', function(e) {
    $(".facetwp-radio[data-value=listings]").click();
});
```

Where now we would have 2 instances of the 'show-*' class each triggering a separate 'click'.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, but I don't think it can be made more versatile than that:

```
$(document).on('click', "div[class^='show-']", function(e) {
    var c = $(this).attr('class').slice('show-'.length);
    $(".facetwp-radio[data-value="+ c +"]").click();
});
```

With div **[class^= 'show-']** I select all the elements that have the class that joins **show-** and then I cut the class to get a substring with the desired text .. :)

**UPDATE:**

You're right .. actually I hadn't thought about that eventuality .. :)

This is how it should go and I have commented the code, so it will be easier for you to understand how it works and make any changes .. :)

```
$(document).on('click', "div[class*='show-']", function(e) {
    var c = $(this).attr('class');  // I read the class of the element 
    c = c.slice(c.indexOf('show-')) // I delete any classes prior to the desired one 
        .split(' ')[0]              // I delete any classes following the desired one
        .slice('show-'.length);     // I delete the "show-" from the class 
    $(".facetwp-radio[data-value="+ c +"]").click();  // If the element exists, then it simulates a click on it. 
});
```

**A LITTLE NOTE:**

the "**div[class^='show-']**" selector selects all classes that **START** with "**show-**". Example:

```
<div class="show-me food dog"></div>
```

the "**div[class*='show-']**" selector selects all class attributes that **CONTAIN** the text "**show-**". Example:

```
<div class="food show-me dog"></div>
```

To avoid conflicts, I would advise you to use the first selector (**div[class^='show-']**), but not knowing the HTML structure of your page, the much more generic second selector may be more useful.

I don't know .. you just have to try! :)

Comment: Thanks Pinguto. Yes it appears to be more versatile alright. Will test both and refer back here. Many thanks for your input.

Comment: Hello again. Just getting back to this now. I did have some success but other classes on the div are also being added and causing an error. Is there a way to stop this from happening do you know?

Comment: I don't understand .. could you give me an example? thank you!

Comment: Updated the original post @Pinguto - Thank you.

Comment: @Briany Hearne I have updated my answer .. =)

Comment: We got there :) Thank you.

Comment: I'm only a noob here @Pinguto but is there a way we can connect outside of SO? I need ongoing 'pro' help and would love to see if we could work together? Only small stuff.... Admins please delete if necessary. Thank you.

Comment: @Briany Hearne Connect outside the OS? To do what? Could you give me another example?

Comment: I was asking if we could get in touch directly outside of Stack Overflow :) @Pinguto

Comment: I read the questions you opened here about stack overflow and I'm afraid I can't help you .. :(

Comment: No problem. Thank you for everything :) @Pinguto

Comment: I'm outstaying my welcome @Pinguto but if you have 2 minutes to take a look. I have added an additional requirement to the initial request. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an example, perhaps a working one, of what you are trying to accomplish? Why do you need another class?

Answer (score -1):

You could create an array of possible entities, then cycle it, e.g.:

```
var items = ['listings', 'albums'];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  $(document).on('click', '.show-' + items[i], function (e) {
    $('.facetwp-radio[data-value="' + items[i] + '"]').click();
  });
}
```

or, if you prefer ES6-style:

```
let items = ['listings', 'albums'];
items.forEach(item => {
  $(document).on('click', `.show-${item}`, e => {
    $(`.facetwp-radio[data-value="${item}"]`).click();
  });
});
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks Alessio.